How to compute $X^{\mu}(z)X^{\nu}(w)=-\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\mu\nu}\ln (z-w)+\cdots $?
I'm studying the book "String theory and M-theory." by Becker, Becker and Schwarz. Unfortunately, I don't understand really well the materials in Chapter 3 "conformal field theory and string interactions". I don't understand OPE (operator product expansion) concept and that why the OPE of a scalar field, like $X^{\mu}$, has the form $$X^{\mu}(z)X^{\nu}(w)=-\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\mu\nu}\ln (z-w)+\cdots $$ and why we sometimes compute $$\langle \partial X^{\mu}(z)\partial X^{\nu}(w)\rangle $$ the correlation function.
I would really appreciate if someone could introduce me to an easier book to understand them.
Could anyone explain to me how to compute the following? $$X^{\mu}(z)X^{\nu}(w)=-\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\mu\nu}\ln (z-w)+\cdots $$
I have trouble with details.

You should try “ Conformal Field Theory” bt Di Francesco (the yellow book).

would you mind to quote the full book title please

@Gold Thank you so much.

@l4teLearner Sure. String theory and M-theory.

thanks. I meant to edit your question indicating the correct title.

@l4teLearner Okay. I'll do it.

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/684737/2451

I recommend looking at chapter 2 of Polchinski's "String Theory", volume 1.
