Why and how to compute $\langle X^{\mu}(z)X^{\nu}(w)\rangle $?
Becker, Becker and Schwarz in the book String theory and M-theory say on page 72 that  $$\partial X^{\mu}(z)\partial X^{\nu}(w)=-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\eta^{\mu\nu}}{(z-w)^2}+\cdots $$ the OPE of two operators $\partial X^{\mu}(z)$ and $\partial X^{\nu}(w)$.
I have some questions:

why does the author compute $\langle \partial X^{\mu}(z)\partial X^{\nu}(w)\rangle$?

why do $\langle \partial X^{\mu}(z)\partial X^{\nu}(w)\rangle$ and $: \partial X^{\mu}(z)\partial X^{\nu}(w):$ mean singular and non-singular parts of $\partial X^{\mu}(z)\partial X^{\nu}(w)$, respectively?

Why we compute $\langle \partial X^{\mu}(z)\partial X^{\nu}(w)\rangle$? or more operators. What does it tell us?


I think there is formula like $$OPE(AB)=\langle AB\rangle +:AB:$$ for two operators $A$ and $B$ that does not exist in the book. Is there such a formula in the physics?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18078/2451 and links therein. Also note that radial ordering is implicitly assumed on the lhs.

Also related since this is almost the same question though this also has yet to be answered since it was more resource recommendation oriented https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/832903/23615
